# User loggoff time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, logoff

I am developing a new Asp.net MVC application and it is important for me to see the logged in users and  if the logout time for them, If the user click on the logout button it is ok for me. But most of the times the users navigate through the browser out of the website or just close the browser. Is there a way to now that. I have an idea to run an action every two minutes to check if the users is there or not. But is it a good idea and what is the risks. If it is, any one has an example how that can be achieved !.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the exact same thing 2 days ago. My approach now is as following:

1. **User logs in**

   - I saved some data in the database like session key and user id to identify him. I am also saving login time and an updated DateTime.
   - I only save this if the user is already authenticated.
2. **User calls an action**

   - I update the DateTime in the database for every action the user performs.
3. **User uses the logoff button**

   - I move the entry in the database from the table "session" to "sessionHistory" and update the DateTime to the logoff time.
4. **User closes browser (This is where it gets tricky)**

   - I built a very small piece of code with jQuery. I call $.get and poke a "UpdatePing" Action in the MVC every 30 Seconds.
   - The "UpdatePing" Action will update the session entry in the database. Now i can see if his Browser is actually still open.
   - **WARNING:** You will not know exactly when the user closed the tab / browser. You could try to use the event "beforeunload", but i wouldn't rely on it (Browser crash etc.).
5. **Removing expired sessions**

   - I do not completely delete the session data. I copy the session data into the "sessionHistory" table.

Comment: I just saw your comment in the other Question (regarding multiple tabs).
You could try and calculate it based on the pings.

Comment: the ping in every session puts a lot of overhead in a competitive environment, especially when you can use one built-in functionality of javascript onbeforeunload. or even ajax control toolkit to ping the server only once when the user closes the window and save the latest request by the user to estimate the EXACT time of the user leaving your app.

Comment: This is true, allthough onbeforeunload will not fire if the browser is not closed properly. If this is not so important, skip the ping and session updates and redirect to the logout page with the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: Thanks  KampfFussel for your response and I really appreciate your help. As I said in the comment bellow and Waqer Ahamed said this will put a load in the server and since we have the same issue together I recommend to you to use SingelR also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript funtion `onbeforeunload` event. 
This function is called when the user navigates away from the page.

on that function put your ajax request to the server that the user unloaded the page at this time and create your logic.

For multiple tabs or multiple devices, the solution is simple. Every multiple tab will be of same session but every new device will have a new session even though the user is the same. 
what can be done for this is to save the latest request for every session regardless of the device. Even tho the user have multiple devices, your log will contain the login time for every session on every device of the user.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have thought about this solution but there is a case here what if the user open multi tabs. How we can detrmine that.

Comment: for multiple tabs, save the latest request received by the user for the current session.

Comment: Yeah I think about that solution but what if the user open multi browser or open it in multi devices. I think this solution will be complicated as the project get bigger. Any way thank you very much for your answer. If you can see my  comment bellow to see if that is a good idea or not.

Comment: i have edited/added the answer for multiple-tabs. if you can see it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers but both answers may got to complicated on the way when the project is going larger. Like for example I am going to support the application with mobile app.
I found that the best solution is use SignalR to send single from the client to the server and when these single stops for a while I will logout the user automatically.

Comment: SignalR after every interval to every user will put a great overhead. APart from this is it will be a huge resource usage.